# Laravel Blade is displaying incorrect values for select dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, select, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I'm creating a form in Blade and one of the `<select>` is of all the months.

```
@php (
$months = [
    '1'=>'01 - January',
    '2'=>'02 - February',
    '3'=>'03 - March',
    '4'=>'04 - April',
    '5'=>'05 - May',
    '6'=>'06 - June',
    '7'=>'07 - July',
    '8'=>'08 - August',
    '9'=>'09 - September',
    '10'=>'10 - October',
    '11'=>'11 - November',
    '12'=>'12 - December',
]
)


{{Form::select('card_month', array_merge(['' => 'Select Month'], $months),null,['id' => 'exp_month'])}}
```

When I use Inspect Element to look at the dropdown I see this 
[image]

The keys in the $months array don't match the values in Inspect Element.
The values start off at 0 instead of 1.

BUT If I add a space in front of the keys, then the numbers display correctly under Inspect Element.

```
' 1'=>'01 - January',
' 2'=>'02 - February',
' 3'=>'03 - March',
' 4'=>'04 - April',
' 5'=>'05 - May',
' 6'=>'06 - June',
' 7'=>'07 - July',
' 8'=>'08 - August',
' 9'=>'09 - September',
' 10'=>'10 - October',
' 11'=>'11 - November',
' 12'=>'12 - December',
```

[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure how `Form::select` works under the hood, but it looks to be using a 0-based index instead of the key of each array value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not Laravel fault, this is how **[array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)** function behaves:

> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the array_merge and it fixed it.